# search for nested text in div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I can select a specific html element using

```
querySelector('.someClassName')
```

And then run tests to check aspects such as textContent.

I'd like to be able to select an element, like I did above, and then check if there is specific text in a nested html element. I'm thinking something like this:

```
expect(someContainer.querySelector('.someClassName').nestedTextContent)
  .toEqual(expect.stringContaining('this is some nested text'))

//nestedTextContent not real: this is something I made up to show what I'd like to achieve
```

Is there something like this? Is my only option to iterate through the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive function to check the `textContent` of each element:

```js
let res = null

function findTextContent(el, txt){

   if(el && el.textContent.trim() === txt){
      res = el
      return res
   }else{
      if(el && el.hasChildNodes()){
         [...el.children].forEach((ch) => {
            return findTextContent(ch, txt)
         })
      }
      
      return res
   }
}

const el = findTextContent(document.querySelector(".grandparent"), "Child text")
el.style.color = "red"
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  Grandparent text
  <div class="parent">
    Parent text
    <div class="child">Wrong child text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    Parent text
    <div class="child">Wrong child text</div>
    <div class="child">Child text</div>
    <div class="child">Wrong child text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect().stringContaining` to check if a string has a certain substring (assuming you are using jest). To get the text contained in the div, use `querySelector(....).innerText` (again, assuming you are using jest and `querySelector` returns an `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I'm trying to query for a parent element and find the text in a nested html element
<div class='a'><div>This is nested content</div></div>